# Trouble returning id from ajax creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, activerecord

I'm learning how to use ajax with rails, and I haven't had much trouble except for one persistent problem. I have a dropdown of addresses that a user has used in the past. I then have a "Use a new address" button that brings up a modal address form. I then want to submit that form through ajax, then add the new address to the dropdown.

While I've had no problem submitting the form or creating the address, for some reason I'm unable to access the id of the created access in my callback. Here's some code for context:

```
class AddressesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :js

  def create
    @address = current_user.addresses.build(params[:address])
    @address.save
    respond_with(@address)
  end

end
```

This should then give the data to create.js.erb. In that file, I have no problem accessing @address.city or @address.state, but as soon as I try to access @address.id, I start getting a 500 server error on my ajax call. I thought this might mean that I would have to add id to attr_accessible in address.rb, but that doesn't seem to have helped either. Is there something that I'm missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I'm an idiot. I didn't realize that escape_javascript shouldn't be used for integers, so I had wrapped @address.id in that, causing the error.

Comment: You should either delete the question or post your solution as an answer so people know it's been solved without reading the whole post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops. The problem was that I didn't realize that escape_javascript shouldn't be used for integers, so I had wrapped @address.id in that, causing the error.